# jQuery DataTables 1.9.0 pagination for NoSQL databases

Tags: datatables, cassandra-2.1

There are some properties of jQuery DataTables 1.9.0, for example `iDisplayStart` and `iTotalRecords`, which help to fetch partial requests from the server using pagination.

This seems to be working fine with databases like MySQL (RDBMS).

But recently we've shifted to NoSQL Cassandra. But the only and major problem we're facing is to migrate jQuery DataTables queries where we used to query rows using start and end limit.

Unfortunately I've not dug deep into Cassandra to find such start and end limit query and I think it even doesn't exists. Also I cannot have id column for my Column Family.
I guess many of you might have been through this issue and might help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad.. I can simply do this.

counts = foo.objects.all().count() //will give me total number of counts.

foo_data = foo.objects.all()

response = foo[iDisplayStart:(iDisplayStart+iDisplayLength)]

/*where response is to send data back to dataTables with parameters 'iDisplayRecords' and 'iTotalRecords'
*/

Comment: is this working ? you wrote the code to client side, or server side ?

Comment: @mars This is a server side script